# how to iterate json object property using *ngFor in Angular 4

Tags: json, angular

I need to iterate the this JSON property using *ngFor.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
    "Id":1,
    "Time":"9:30",
    "Status":"Delivered",
    "Date":"20170623",
    "Quantity":2,
    "MetaDataStr":{
        "gender":true,
        "category":"Home Cook",
        "fullName":"Sachin patil",
        "imageURL":"ht/medias/57",
        "description":"hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: This question had been answered many times before. Please do some research first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
export class AppComponent {
    data = { "id": 1, "Time": "9:30", "Status": "Delivered", "Date": "20170623" };
    keys: string[];
    ngOnInit() {
        this.keys = Object.keys(this.data);
    }
}

// In template:

<div *ngFor="let prop of keys">
    <label> {{ prop }}:</label><div>{{ data[prop] }} </div>
</div>
```